# codeigniter passing the same information (like login status) to all the views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using DX_AUTH to handle autentication in my codeigniter app.
I want to display in each page the login status, I'm used to develop my view throught template inheritance.

I'm looking for a way to access login information from the views without passing it each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views shouldn't engage themselves in "lookups".  Why not make a template view that can be passed your authentification information.  Then, build a template controller, from which all other controllers inherit, that passes the authentification info to the template view.  That way, you only write the code once for the template view and the template controller.